# Как лучше сравнивать даты?

Tags: c++

Необходимо в цикле сравнивать даты, в чем у меня может быть ошибка?

```
bool operator >=(const Date &d1, const Date &d2)
{
    return std::tie(d1.year, d1.month, d1.day, d1.hour, d1.minute) >=
    std::tie(d2.year, d2.month, d2.day, d2.hour, d2.minute);
}
```

Переопределил оператор

```
struct Date
{
     int year;
     int month;
     int day;
     int hour;
     int minute;

     Date(int y, int m, int d, int h = 10, int mi = 10) : year(y), month(m), day(d),hour(h), minute(mi) {}
};
```

Структура с датами

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (bars[i].date > end)
        break;
    if (bars[i].date >= start)
        currentBar.push_back(bars[i]);
}
```

Вот цикл, в котором сравниваю. При отладке значения корректно добавлены, в массиве bars последние элементы 2018 года, а start 2016 года.
Но он не заходит по условию.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: А вы не пробовали так?

`bool operator >=(const Date &d1, const Date &d2)
{
    return !(std::tie(d1.year, d1.month, d1.day, d1.hour, d1.minute) <
    std::tie(d2.year, d2.month, d2.day, d2.hour, d2.minute));
}`

Comment: Нет, всё равно не заходит. Возможно дело в ссылках\указателях и т п. Где-то теряются данные и поэтому он при заходе в мой метод оператора берет из их пустоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу вам предложить такую реализацию. С перегрузкой оператора "меньше". Часы и минуты добавить по тому же принципу.

```
class Date {
public:
// конструктор выбрасывает исключение, если его аргументы некорректны
Date(int new_year, int new_month, int new_day) {
year = new_year;
if (new_month > 12 || new_month < 1) {
  throw logic_error("Month value is invalid: " + to_string(new_month));
}
month = new_month;
if (new_day > 31 || new_day < 1) {
  throw logic_error("Day value is invalid: " + to_string(new_day));
}
day = new_day;
}

int GetYear() const {
return year;
}
int GetMonth() const {
return month;
}
int GetDay() const {
return day;
}
private:
int year;
int month;
int day;
};

bool operator<(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) {
// воспользуемся тем фактом, что векторы уже можно сравнивать на <:
// создадим вектор из года, месяца и дня для каждой даты и сравним их
return vector<int>{lhs.GetYear(), lhs.GetMonth(), lhs.GetDay()} <
  vector<int>{rhs.GetYear(), rhs.GetMonth(), rhs.GetDay()};
}
```

Comment: Написал всё, как вы указали, но всё равно не заходит в условие.
if (start < bars[i].date)
 currentBar.push_back(bars[i]);
start имеет year 2000. bars[i].date имеет year 2013. должен быть true, но выдает false. Если поменять знак, то выдает true. Но это неправильно же

Comment: Как оказывается, нужно сравнивать именно по ссылкам даты. Т.е. 
`&start < &bars[i].date` - данная запись будет корректной. А можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы не нужно было дописывать амперсанд?